# How to map elements in 2d numpy array without using for-loop?

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, mapping

I want to reorganize the elements in a 2d numpy array based on data stored in a list of lists.
The below (simplified) minimum code example does exactly what I intend to do, but by using a rather slow for-loop.
My real application involves much larger 2d arrays and because the reorganisation process is time-critical I would like to get rid of the for-loop and only use the (much faster) vectorized numpy operations. I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to replace the for-loop construction by a more intelligent numpy-based coding.

```
import numpy as np

states = np.array([["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]])
pos_new = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
pos_old = [[1, 2], [2, 0]] 

for idx in range(len(states)):
    states[idx][pos_new[idx]] = states[idx][pos_old[idx]]

print(states)
```

I expect the following output (as produced by the above code):

```
[['b' 'c' 'c' 'd'] 
 ['C' 'B' 'A' 'D']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fancy indexing:

```
idx = np.arange(len(states))[:, None]

states[idx, pos_new] = states[idx, pos_old]
```

*NB. This is only equivalent to the loop if no target value depends on a previously replaced value.*

Output:

```
array([['b', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
       ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D']], dtype='<U1')
```